# How to make jquery events work in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, dom-events

I am trying to add a function to some elements but it just doesn't work or show any error. It seems that the event is just not being inserted and I don't get why, since I am doing exactly the same process in another element and it works fine.

Here is the code where that doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<div id="mainSlider" style="height:100%"></div>

<div id="slider__marker_container">
   <div id="slider__marker_thumbnails"></div>
   <div id="slider__marker_icons"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery (Look for comment 'inserting dots' in the end)

```
$.getScript("../../data/mainSliderData.js", function() {

        const windowWidth = $(window).width()
        const mainSliderContainer = $('#mainSlider')
        mainSliderContainer.css('width', windowWidth * 7)

        const dataArr = $.map(returnData(), value => {
            return [value]
        })

        $.each(dataArr, (index, value) => {

            // Inserting images
            
            const mainSliderDiv = $('<div></div>')
            
            if (index === 0) {
                mainSliderDiv.css("background-image", `url(${value})`)
                mainSliderDiv.addClass('slider__img slide--js')

                mainSliderDiv.appendTo(mainSliderContainer)
            } else {
                mainSliderDiv.css({"background-image": `url(${value})`})
                mainSliderDiv.addClass('slider__img slide--js')
                
                mainSliderDiv.appendTo(mainSliderContainer)
            }

            // Inserting de thumbnails 
            const thumbnailDiv = $('<div></div>')
            const thumbnailImg = $('<img>')
            const thumbnailArrow = $('<i></i>')

            thumbnailDiv.attr('id', `slider__thumbnail_js-${index + 1}`)
            thumbnailDiv.addClass('slider__thumbnail')
            thumbnailImg.attr('src', value)
            thumbnailArrow.addClass('flaticon-down-arrow')
            
            thumbnailImg.appendTo(thumbnailDiv)
            thumbnailArrow.appendTo(thumbnailDiv)
            thumbnailDiv.appendTo('#slider__marker_thumbnails')

            // Inserting dots
            const sliderMarker = $('<i></i>')

            sliderMarker.addClass('flaticon-circle mainMarker--js')
            if (index === 0) {sliderMarker.addClass('flaticon-circle mainMarker--js markerT')}

            sliderMarker.on('click', () => test()) // => EVENT DOESN'T WORK

            sliderMarker.appendTo('#slider__marker_icons')

        })

    }) .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
        console.log('error:')
        console.log(exception)
    })
```

OUTCOME:

[image]

The same logic in another element, but here it works:

```
$.getScript('../../data/novosProdutosData.js', function () {

        $.each(returnData(), (index, value) => {

            const slideDiv = $('<div></div>')
            const slideLink = $('<a></a>')
            const slideImg = $('<img>')
            const slideDescriptionDiv = $('<div></div>')
            const slideDescriptionTitle = $(`<p>${value.nome}<br>${value.material}</p>`)
            const slideDescriptionPrice = $(`<p>R$ ${value.preco}</p>`)
            const slideDescriptionArrow = $('<i></i>')

            slideDiv.addClass('promo__container--slider-uni')
            slideImg.attr('src', value.img)
            slideDescriptionDiv.addClass('promo__container--slider-description')
            slideDescriptionPrice.addClass('promo__container--slider-preco')
            slideDescriptionArrow.addClass('flaticon-right-arrow promo__container--description-arrow')
            
            slideDescriptionTitle.appendTo(slideDescriptionDiv)
            slideDescriptionPrice.appendTo(slideDescriptionDiv)
            slideDescriptionArrow.appendTo(slideDescriptionDiv)
            slideImg.appendTo(slideLink)
            slideDescriptionDiv.appendTo(slideLink)
            slideLink.appendTo(slideDiv)
            slideDiv.appendTo('.promo__container--slider-bloco')

        })

        let dotsQtd = Math.floor(returnData().length / 4)

        for (let i = 0; i < dotsQtd; i++) {

            let dotIcon = $('<i></i>')

            dotIcon.addClass('flaticon-circle marker-amostras--js')
            if (i === 0) {dotIcon.addClass('flaticon-circle marker-amostras--js markerT2')}
            dotIcon.on('click', () => test()) // => EVENT WORKS FINE
            dotIcon.appendTo('.promo__container--header-markerSlider')
        }

    })
```

Any idea why this is happening will be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I kept digging until find the problem. It hadn't anything to do with JQuery. This is a slider and I am using JS to change the position of the element with `transform: translateX()`, in order to change the image, the problem was laying there. When I applied `transform` to the slider, its parent div was was covering the div that wraps the icons, so I couldn't click on the icons, what made me thought that the problem was with the event. I hadn't thought about that because I didn't change anything on the structure of the code besides using `transform: translateX()`, so it didn't passed through my mind.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - check if event even reaches to TEST() function.

second - why You are using promise here at all? As far as I can understand, you only need on-doc-ready. Any other action can be done with on("eventname", function());

Comment: Hello. I already checked the function, it was the first thing I did. It's not being reached. `you only need on-doc-ready`: I didn't put it here, but I am doing that. `getScript` is wrapped by it.

Comment: `Any other action can be done with on("eventname", function())`: That's the point, it should work, probably there is some detail I am not able to see. And as you see, in the second example the code works and it has the same logic of the first one. This is what is tricking me.

Comment: how far you can reach!? that is the main question. seams like for some reason youre promise does not fire.

Comment: I don't know. The tests I could do is trying to fire it using other elements, and it works. I tried with the main element, `mainSliderDiv`, for example, which is created in the same loop and it works fine. The problem seems to be just with `sliderMarker`. But I can't see where.

Comment: I just figured it out, maybe. const is const - once you set it, you cannot change it. let can be change always inside the current function and functions inside that current function, var is changable all around the code (https://medium.com/@josephcardillo/the-difference-between-var-let-and-const-in-javascript-part-2-60fa568d0a0). therefor: change `const sliderMarker = $('<i></i>')` to `let sliderMarker = $('<i></i>')`

Comment: Hello, man. I had thought about that already, it doesn't change anything. But I found the problem, it hadn't anything to do with jquery. I made an edit to my question. Thank you very much for your time anyway.